# apr_dso_load faild to load DSO

Tags: c, dll, shared-libraries, apr

I tried to run unimrcpserver v1.0 with my asr plugin and it worked fine (on windows 7), but when I tried to run it in another machine (windows server 2003), I had this error message

```
2012-08-01 03:57:31:930875 [WARN]   Failed to Load DSO: This application has failed
 to start because the application configuration is incorrect. 
    Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

the server can not load the DLL library ..
is this problem OS specific? cause the problem occurs in apr_dso_load() function which calls OS specific functions.
what is meant by application configuration and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This library that you are trying to load, loads other libraries? seems that this other libraries cant be found. If you are in windows use dependency walker, if you are in linux use ldd to know dependencies.